# How to pass date in angulajs GET request

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass date field in angularjs $http Get request into asp.net web api. Please suggest me that what is the correct way to pass date field.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make your own service, some:

```
.service('AjaxService', function($http){
    var get = function(function_name, parameters, url){
        url = url || '/action';
        var data = {
            parameters: parameters,
            function_name: function_name
            time: getDate()
        };
        return $http.get(url, data)
    };

    var getDate = function(){
        //Get date in whatever format you want
        return new Date().toUTCString();
    };

    return{
        get: get
    }
})
```

And then when you want to do the http get request just call:

```
AjaxService.get(function_name, parameters, url);
```

Ofcourse, don't forget to inject service to the controller.